# Want to connect mongodb docker service with my django application

Tags: django, mongodb, docker

[image: while running docker-compose up getting this error.]I want to create **two docker services** one is mongodb service another one is web service build using django. And i need that web-service (django app) which need to be connected to that mongodb docker service.

but i dont know how to **connect with mongodb docker service in my django** application which is also a service running in a same docker swarm .`This is **my docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Here i tried with mongoengine in **settings.py** of django application but failed

```
MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = "reg_task21"
MONGO_HOST = "mongo"

mongoengine.connect(db=MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, host=MONGO_HOST,port=27017)
```

Comment: please do format your question

Comment: Your docker compose file seem to be correct. What happened when you do docker-compose up?

Comment: Minh Tri Le.

Yes i guess. But I'm not sure how to establish connection with my django application and mongodb docker service. I want to use that mongo service name to connect with database but what's the exact syntax i'm not sure

Comment: ` Minh Tri Le
Here im adding part of my settings.py of django application

"""
Django settings for reg_example project.

import os
import mongoengine

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }



MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = "reg_task2"
MONGO_HOST = "mongo"

mongoengine.connect(db=MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, host=MONGO_HOST, port=27017)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `username` and `password` to connect statement:

```
mongoengine.connect(db=MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, username='root', password='example', host=MONGO_HOST,port=27017)
```